# Cannot see entire background height when page loads

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the background image of my div. Basically, I have a background image 1500px width and 745px height.
When the page loads, I'd like to see the full height of the image (so the image fits the height of the div). I'd like the behavior to be something like this: http://www.wearegather.org/

My html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div id="home">
        </div>

        <footer>
        </footer>
   </div>
</body>
```

The css:

```
body
{
margin:0 auto 0px;
width: 1500px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #B1B3B4;
width: 100%;
}

header
{
margin: 0px auto 0px;
width: 960px;
height:110px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

nav
{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 10px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

nav ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
}

nav li
{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 15px;
}

#home {
 border: 1px solid green;
 margin-top:50px;
 background: url(http://www.wearegather.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/armscycles11.jpg) no-repeat fixed;

 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

But when the page is loaded, the image cannot be seen in its whole height (the bottom part does not appear).

I've tried to add some jquery stuff but it's not working as expected. Can this be achieved without javascript ?

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I have added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RuqP/8/

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should accomplish your task. Just apply to the style of the div that should have the background:

```
background-image: url('../images/home.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 
background-size:100% 100%;
```

You can play around with additional stretching using the background-size style, by adding higher percentiles.

Comment: I've tried but the whole height of the image is not shown in the div. the upper part of the image is truncated.

Comment: @Luc Do you mind creating a JS Fiddle? I'm sure we can figure it out - but it would definitely assist others looking at your question. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for help. I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5RuqP/ I've trying to use the same image as the one used in the site I use as an example but the background is not loaded.